# Trying to understand electron flow in a rapid start ballast fluorescent light system

Tags: current, electron, ballast

While looking into what is required to upgrade a fluorescent tube light to a LED solution, I found that I don't truly understand what is happening with existing fluorescent solutions.

I understand the electron flow in a fluorescent lamp starter circuit - that part is obvious to me.  I get it for an instant start circuit where there is a single wire going to each end of the tube.  I don't get the electron flow in a rapid start solution which has two wires going to each end of a tube, across a filament:

[image: Rapid start ballast]

If current is flowing in the same direction in both blue wires as the light switch is turned on, then how can current flow at all as there is not yet a completed circuit before the lamp is charged?

Do electrons at first travel from the ballast down one blue wire, across the filament to heat it up and back along the second blue wire back to the ballast, and likewise for the red wires in the second lamp?  Then when the lamp is finally charged and electrons travel down the tube, are the common wires are used to complete the circuit, somehow favoured over the previous blue return, or are they both used?

This would sort of make sense to me when I read about how the ballast heats up the filaments and continues to simutaneously heat the filament before, during and after the lamp charges.  So, some electrons travel across the filament, heating it up, and return by the other blue wire, while other electrons travel through the tube and return via the common wire(s.)

I read labels on ballasts that say high voltage is on blue and red wires and I read one article suggesting power was provided in parallel on the two blue wires (which I interpreted as meaning in the same direction.)  I would assume if there is a different direction of current flow between each of the blue wires, that they would be different colours, or that one of those wires would also be labeled as "Common".

If there is current flow in the same direction for both blues (and reds for the second lamp,) then what is really happening?  Why two wires to each end?  Is each wire providing the same voltage/current or is something different happening on each wire?  Why couldn't it just be one wire then - basically like an instant start ballast but starting at a lower voltage to heat the filament?

I'm so confused.

Comment: Don't think about electrons flowing. Think of "conventional" current, which flows in the opposite direction. In any case, this is AC current where the direction reverses 50/60 times a second so it's immaterial.

Comment: The ballasts shown most probably are not mains frequency/("electro")magnetic: EM, but "electronic"/"high (above audible) frequency": HF. *Rapid start* may mean *without flicker within one second*, or *within a fraction of a second (without flicker)* - without unmistakable delay.

Comment: @Finbarr That's AC alright but has nothing to do with 50 or 60 Hz. Those are electronic ballasts that can be more considered as special power supplies or drivers for fluorescent tubes, likely working at several if not in tens of kHz frequencies to bring down the transformer cost. And, it is likely that LED replacements are only compatible with standard ballast transformers and not compatible with electronic ballasts.